# Make BeaconManager listen for more than 1 Region/beacon

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

This is my code so far:
This method goes through the list of beacon objects I have saved in my DB, and create a region for every beacon in the list:

```
 for (nl.hgrams.passenger.model.vehicle.Beacon beacon : beacons) {
            if (beacon.getUser_vehicle() != null) {
                Utils.appendLog("Added a beacon region for: " + beacon.getName(), "I", Constants.TRACKER);
                Region region = new Region("all-beacons-region", Identifier.parse(beacon.getUuid()), null, null);
                regions.add(region);
            }
        }
```

Then I go through the list, and call `startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region):`

```
  try {
        for (Region region : regions) {
            beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
        }
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.e("", "region error trying to start ranging beacons in region");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But what I noticed is that it will listen only to the last Region it monitored.
Why doesn't it listen to all of them? How can I make it listen to all regions?
Is it possible to pass more uuids to a region or something like that , that will fix this?

## EDIT:

I tried using this:

```
 PSApplicationClass.getInstance().regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(bootstrapNotifier, regions);
```

With the RegionBootstrap with my Application class implementing the boostrapNotifier.
Using it with the regions list created with the code of the for Loop I have before the EDIT.
But I get EnteredRegion called once, and then I get no more EXIT, or ENTERED events, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was here:
`Region region = new Region("all-beacons-region", Identifier.parse(beacon.getUuid()), null, null);`
I was setting the first arg. for all regions as: `all-beacons-region` which would case them to be overriden. Hence why only the last was being called

Comment: Glad that you found it and that it was so simple!

Comment: Thanks. I missunderstood the tutorial, thinking I need to have "all-beacons-region" as the first argument. Took me a while to understand that that's the uniqueID. totally my fault